# HTML download movie download link

Tags: javascript, html, download, move

I want a user to be able to hit a button which triggers a .mov file to download. Linking to the file its self just causes the movie to play in a new page.

I have tried this:

```
<a onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'assets/files/mymovie.mov');" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

But this does not seem to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the html5 download attribute.

```
<a href='assets/files/mymovie.mov' download>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Musa's answer:

Try setting the `Content-Disposition` header. You will need to set this up either in your server configuration, or let a executable script on your server do this (such as php):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mymovie.mov"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a server side page to serve up content, by chance, then you can easily set the header of that page `Content-Disposition: attachment` and/or `Content-Type:binary` so that it kicks off a download.

otherwise, you can use download attribute in your `<a>` tag, which will only work in some browsers.

lastly, if you're feeling really heroic, you can go hack on your mime-types settings config file in your web server, in which you'd set the content disposition there.