# How to make HTML Link which makes the user download an .html file

Tags: html, file, download

The following code will make the user download the `.doc` file

```
<a href="http://something.abc/file.doc">Download</a>
```

I want to create a link that will let user to download `.html` file

Any Ideas how to do it....???

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313082/html-download-movie-download-link

Comment: I want and HTML link to let user download an `.html` file, above link was about download a `.mov` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 [Download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) in the anchor tag.

Download attribute signifies that the resource it points to should be downloaded by the browser instead of navigating to it.

```
<a href="myfile.html" download> Download HTML file </a>
```

or, you can specify a name of the downloadable file by yourself

```
<a href="myfile.html" download="file.html"> Download with specified name </a>
```

Not all browsers support this HTML5 attribute, [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) is the detail of where it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `download` atributte to the `<a>` tag.
We'll get something like this:
`<a href="file.html" download>Download</a>`

**Note:** The `download` attribute **IS NOT** supported in Internet Explorer.
In this case, it's better to zip the html file (add it into a *.rar* or a *.zip*, *WinRAR* can do this) and link it.

It'll be: `<a href="htmlFile.zip">Click me</a>`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way to provide a .html file for download to a user would be to put it in a .zip or .rar format.